# Mesh partly shows wireframe upon texturing

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: Texture problem]
As you can see from the attached image, there is a problem with the texturing. I have not yet added a texture, but simply went into texture mode, and part of the mesh shows a wireframe as compared to being white like the rest of the mesh. This part is the "backside" of the cape; it doesn't show the the white color, whereas the "front-side" does. The cape is just a plane with many vertices. This also holds true for the inside of other parts of the mesh like the shirt, shorts etc. When I did add a texture image, the error still persisted. What is causing this, and how can it be resolved?

UPDATE:
Backface culling is disabled.
I am using blender version 2.69.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have enabled `Backface Culling`, either in the material's settings if you are in the game engine or in the viewport's shading settings:

Game engine material settings:
[image]

Viewport shading settings:
[image]

Disable it and you should see the texture of your object on both sides.

This is not a bug in Blender but an optimization technique which is used in games to reduce the GPU load. If you have a closed mesh you can not see the backsides anyway. Only if your mesh is not closed you need to draw both sides.

Comment: I've updated the question; I've not enabled backface culling; the mesh is a cape, so it is a big deal that this is happening.

Comment: actually, two things fixed the problem: extruding the mesh a bit so that it is no longer a plane, and also upgrading to v2.72b. The error no longer presents itself if I do this, if you have another suggestion as to how it can be fixed, please do share. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like backface culling was always active in the old Blender version. Maybe this was a bug after all. If you extrude your mesh you will again get a closed mesh, so you will always see front faces.